# Calico-node pods not becoming READY until iptables is disabled - Kubernetes on RHEL 7

Tags: iptables, redhat, kubernetes, calico, kubeadm

I have provisioned a Kubernetes cluster on RHEL 7 and deployed Calico to it. The `calic-node` pods running on the master and worker nodes do not become `ready` until I SSH into the master and temporarily disable iptables with `systemctl stop iptables`.

I have configured iptables on the master to allow incoming access over TCP to `6443`, `2379:2380`, and `10250:10252`. So it should be configured correctly as per the documented required ports. After all, the nodes are able to join the cluster via `kubeadm join` which requires the ability to network with the master over `6443`.

Comment: It is possible to check if the issue is due to blocked ports, however, in addtion to 6443 can you open 443 and 8080 and check one more time? (https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/controlling-access/) . Addtionally it would be good to see FW config.

Comment: I added another answer with the solution. I had to add a few ports for Calico to each node. I have deployed Kubernetes a few dozen times before with Kubeadm and never had to forward these ports. However, before now I have always used firewalld rather than iptables for managing OS port forwarding. I'm unsure why this migration required the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was also including the ports defined [here](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/requirements).